# Error while add new item in a custom list sharepoint 2010

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, custom-list

I am getting an error while trying to add a new item in the custom list..it was working before, but now it is throwing the following error

[image]
any suggestions?

Comment: Take a look in your ULS logs, find that correlation ID and update your question with the information you find.  This will help people diagnose the problem.

Comment: Is there any custom code on this list like an event receiver or a custom field type?

Comment: yes Dave there is a event receiver and i have wrote some jquery in the forms too

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As chris is saying, please look in to your ULS logs.
This will say where the problem is occuring.

How to do so?
Do the same operations again, so the error occures again. 
Copy the correlation ID (without leading and tracing spaces) and open the latest log file (found in 14\Logs) and search this document for ur correlation ID (control + f).

Check everyline that is showing "Unexpected" AND includes your correlation ID.
If you have no idea what to do, feel free to upload a link to your log file and give me your correlation ID. I can have a look for u.

Comment: hmm.... this is not a valid answer :)

Comment: Thanks, Frederik, but that doesn't really add anything to Chris's comment.

Comment: Well it was not ment for answer. But I couldn't add a comment (no idea why, the "add comment" button is not visible for me on the original post). So it was either not helping, or putting an answer. So next time, i will not answer since this is not being appreciated. Thanks for marking this "-1", since this DO is an answer. If you got a correlation ID, ULS log almost always IS the solution. Any experienced SP Developer should now, that in 90% of the cases, the error is explained in detail in the ULS log. :-)

Comment: And whenever someone new reads this topic, who has no idea where to find the ULS logs, will now know how to find it. but well...

Comment: Thanks!...that did it, i checked the ULS logs it was one of the lookupfields which was missing in the list so i added it ..now i am able to add a new item to the list ..but when i try to open the newform.aspx in the designer i am getting "the server returned a non specific error while trying to get data from the data source check the format and content of the query and try again" ..any suggestions?..i am able to see and edit the code but not the UI

Answer (score 0):

This error message occurs on SP 2007 because of workflow, sometimes. You can deatach it (thru list settings) and attach it again (thru designer, open and save), if it helps.

And second thing, make sure, that you don't copy text to multiple text fields from external programs, field preserves formatting and imported html can be wrong without end tags.